# Building Android source: error when executing mm?

Tags: android, compilation, makefile, android-source, rom

**Update**

I got this working. How I am not sure. I did no config changes at all. What I did was:

- Modify `Dialog` in `frameworks/base/core/java/android/app`.
- Went to my root (`/path/to/source/`).
- Then I did `mmm frameworks/base/`.

Everything worked. Then I  tried *exactly* what I had already tried below:

- Modify `ScrollView` (I actually never said which file I was modifying) in `frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget`.
- I `ch`'ed to `frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget`.
- Then I did `mm`.

This time I had no errors like before when the files were removed. Now it just works.

Maybe this was some caching or bug?

**/Update**

I am building the Android source code for the emulator. I built the whole code with `make -j32` and the system.img gets to the output `out/target/product/generic/system.img`. The emulator works simply by calling `emulator`.

When I do changes in `frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget`, using the `hmm` documentation, the most appropriate command would be `mm` to build the current directory.

Unfortunately I get an error:

> make: * No rule to make target
>
> `out/target/product/generic/system/framework/framework-res.apk',
>
> needed by `out/target/product/generic/system/framework/framework.jar'.
>
> Stop.
>
> make: Leaving directory
>   `/path/to/source/'

Leaving me to do `make -j32` again to get the emulator to run and apply my fixes.

Checking the `out/target/product/generic/` folder after using the `mm` command, system.img has been removed with several other things.

When I read the logs this is printed:

> *** Forcing "make installclean"...
>
> *** rm -rf out/target/product/generic/data/* out/target/product/generic/data-qemu/*
>
> out/target/product/generic/userdata-qemu.img
>
> out/host/linux-x86/obj/NOTICE_FILES out/host/linux-x86/sdk
>
> out/target/product/generic/*.img out/target/product/generic/*.txt
>
> out/target/product/generic/*.xlb out/target/product/generic/*.zip
>
> out/target/product/generic/kernel out/target/product/generic/data
>
> out/target/product/generic/obj/APPS
>
> out/target/product/generic/obj/NOTICE_FILES
>
> out/target/product/generic/obj/PACKAGING
>
> out/target/product/generic/recovery out/target/product/generic/root
>
> out/target/product/generic/system
>
> out/target/product/generic/dex_bootjars
>
> out/target/product/generic/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES
>
> out/target/product/generic/obj/FAKE
>
> out/target/product/generic/obj/EXECUTABLES/adbd_intermediates
>
> out/target/product/generic/obj/EXECUTABLES/init_intermediates
>
> out/target/product/generic/obj/ETC/mac_permissions.xml_intermediates
>
> out/target/product/generic/obj/ETC/sepolicy_intermediates
>
> *** Done with the cleaning, now starting the real build. make: Entering directory `/path/to/source/'

My guess is that it will clean "outdated" data and then rebuild it with the already prebuilt Android source code BUT with my changes in the `frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget` folder.

Is this the right approach? I was under the impression `mm` would compile what was needed in the current directory and somehow insert this data to the system.img.

I have also seen the command `mm -B`, what does the `-B` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happened to me too.

I was able to solve it by using the mmm command.

From within the framework/base folder, I did:

```
mmm .
```

and after that all "mm" commands worked.

"mm -B" vs "mm":
The -B switch if forcing the build w/o the use of any existing obj files (as doing clean and then build), where the "mm" command alone will use any existing obj files and continue the build from there. 
If you have a successful build - you can see that running "mm" won't do a thing, where "mm -B" will do a full build of the current module.

Comment: I see, thank you. Do you know why `mm` did not work the first time?

Comment: No, I have no idea. 
It's especially weird because I'm pretty sure that running "mmm <path>" or "mm" inside the <path> should do the same.

Comment: I did a make clean and make, after that both `mm` and `mmm` stopped working for the folder `frameworks/base/`. What I did to fix it was to use the command `mmm frameworks/base/core/res`, then I could use my previous commands.

Comment: I had that issue again and your command "mmm frameworks/base/core/res" solved it for me too.